# NullPointerException - Attempt to get length of null array (readDirectory())

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, directory

I have the code as shown here. 
My Problem is a NullPointerException at files.length

```
for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++){
```

It is caused because i have a "fail readDirectory() errno=13" at

```
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

But why do I have a readDirectory fail when the path is good?

```
package com.example.androidexplorer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);

Log.v("Path: ", dirPath);

        Log.v("BEFORE", "Before Reading Fail...");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        Log.v("AFTER", "After Reading Fail...");


        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());    
        }

        Log.v("CRASH", "1 Line before crash");
        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++){
            Log.v("AFTER CRASH", "1 Line after crash");
            File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }   
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead()){
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();  
            }   
        }else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

          }
    }

}
```

LogCat:

> ```
> > 04-23 15:35:34.084: D/ResourcesManager(20672): creating new
> > AssetManager and set to
> > /data/app/com.example.androidexplorer-1/base.apk 04-23 15:35:34.104:
> > I/art(20672): Created application space
> > /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.androidexplorer-1@base.apk@classes.dex.art
> > at 0x76eb0000~0x76f15ff8 04-23 15:35:34.104: I/art(20672): Loaded art
> > file:
> > /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.androidexplorer-1@base.apk@classes.dex.art
> > 04-23 15:35:34.194: V/BitmapFactory(20672):
> > DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) :
> > res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png 04-23 15:35:34.204:
> > V/BitmapFactory(20672): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) :
> > res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png 04-23 15:35:34.234:
> > D/AbsListView(20672): Get MotionRecognitionManager 04-23 15:35:34.244:
> > V/BitmapFactory(20672): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) :
> > res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > V/Path:(20672): /storage/emulated/0 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > V/BEFORE(20672): Before Reading Fail... 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/File(20672): fail readDirectory() errno=13 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > V/AFTER(20672): After Reading Fail... 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > V/CRASH(20672): 1 Line before crash 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > D/AndroidRuntime(20672): Shutting down VM 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/AndroidRuntime(20672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Process: com.example.androidexplorer, PID:
> > 20672 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> > ComponentInfo{com.example.androidexplorer/com.example.androidexplorer.MainActivity}:
> > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 04-23
> > 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):  at
> > android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 04-23
> > 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):  at
> > android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834) 04-23
> > 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):  at
> > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 04-23 15:35:34.254:
> > E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 04-23
> > 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by:
> > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > com.example.androidexplorer.MainActivity.getDir(MainActivity.java:57)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > com.example.androidexplorer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 04-23
> > 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):  at
> > android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
> > 04-23 15:35:34.254: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 10 more
> ```

**UPDATE**

Error was in my manifest with the permissions. 
What I had at the beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spicysoftware.infoid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".sysinfo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".daten"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".storage"></activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Updated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spicysoftware.infoid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".sysinfo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".daten"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".storage"></activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
f.listFiles()
```

will return null if the path does not exist.

Please check your path.

**Update**

Android will also require a permission to read certain files.
Maybe you need to add this to your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

More information:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Thank you! My Problem was that I have set the permission on the wrong place... See my updated answer!

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is go into your manifest file and under the backup line just paste it

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

i have check the condition

File folderPath = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

```
    if (folderPath.exists()) {}
```

for my code and it works for me becuase when this file attemp to read data there were no directory exist on the storage so that it was giving error.

now works fine