# Android: What E/Perf stands for?

Tags: android, kotlin

My android app craches somethimes and only erros I can see at logcat are

```
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.company.app_id
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.company.app_id
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Does  anybody has an idea what this '**Perf**' stands for?

Comment: E means error.  You'll also see W for warning and a few others.

Perf is the tag.  Something in your code seems to be catching an exception and outputting a log without the complete exception.  You should probably change that to output the whole stack trace for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but:
according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb), perf means performance or perform, and E/ means error, you might find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825198/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-get-length-of-null-array-readdirectory) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450949/android-getting-nullpointerexception-for-no-specific-reason) or just by googling any of the error messages